# does the max function holds the triangle inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I need to prove if the following is a norm:
$$||f||:=\max_{-1<x<0}|f| + \max_{0<x<1}|f|$$
when $f$ is a continuous on $[-1,1]$.
The only problem I have is with showing it holds the triangle inequality.
My question is, what I can say about the max function that can help me with the last part?

Comment: hint : max -1<x<0 is a norm on [-1, 0] so it holds the triangle inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N_{-}(f)={\sf max}_{-1<x<0}|f(x)|$ and $N_{+}(f)={\sf max}_{0<x<1}|f(x)|$

It suffices to show that $N_{-}$ and $N_{+}$ each satisfy the triangle inequality
individually.

Let $x\in (0,1)$. Then $|(f+g)(x)| \leq |f(x)|+|g(x)| \leq N_{-}(f)+N_{-}(g)$.
Since this is true for all $x$, we deduce $N_{-}(f+g) \leq N_{-}(f)+N_{-}(g)$.

Similarly for $N_{+}$.

Comment: $$|f(x)|+|g(x)|≤N_−(f)+N_−(g)$$ this is the part i don't understand how to prove

Comment: @rozeshmonim This is because $|f(x)| <N_{-}(f)$ and $|g(x)| <N_{-}(g)$. Just add teh two inequalities